vis.gam() problem with colours: plot without colour surface
I'm trying to plot a bam() model:
vis.gam(model1, 
        view = c('xcoord', 'ycoord'), 
        plot.type = "persp",
        type='link')


But there are no colors. It started suddenly today, once yesterday all was going well. Is there some tricky here?
Could I suppose it is a conflict among packages once I installed new others today. I just couldn't got what is the ugly one!
